# PayPal Mobile SDK ReturnUrl no longer available?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We're using PayPal Native Checkout SDK and configured a returnUrl for our App on the Sandbox some time ago. Now we wanted to do this on LIVE-Environment but the feature is gone :/

I can still see our configuration in the response of the webpage, but on the page itself the button is gone. :(

[image]

Is there any other way now to configure return url for mobile apps?
According to the documentation, it should still be there...
[image]

I know there is Auto Return on some other config page in account settings but as far as I understood that's something different and there we can only configure URIs starting with https://.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Log in with PayPal section

Comment: That's right. No idea why, but we had to activate login with paypal although we don't use it to configure this.